# Why would one want to pass an object from one activity to another on android?

Tags: android, serialization, parcelable

I am trying to learn how `Serializable & Parcelable` works. But I'm not able to understand when to use these interfaces?

Why anyone want to use these interfaces when one can pass data with bundle.
Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest code you can write is to make the object public so in the other activity you can write lastActivity.yourObject

But it is not the best answer i guess!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass objects between activities, this objects need to implement Serializable or Parcelable interface.

Comment: I know when to use it. But why one need to pass object between activities/fragment when it can be done with bundle!

Comment: You can't put object inside bundle, you need that this object will be serializable or parcelable